# Add method to Mono library

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to run an existing web project in Mono that uses version 4.5 of the .NET framework.  I'm using xsp4 to run this through Mono.  I run into an error when I try to access the website on localhost:

```
Missing method System.Web.HttpApplication::RegisterModule(Type) in assembly /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll, referenced in assembly /private/var/folders/xw/1k49vb85533_tl4rn3t6tygw0000gn/T/calvinfroedge-temp-aspnet-0/e60f00e7/assembly/shadow/df4b0596/f4b9d264_2bf2d7f2_00000001/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll
```

I'm aware that the issue is the missing method 'RegisterModule' in 'System.Web.HttpApplication.'  My question is, how can I add this method to the Mono source on my machine and recompile so that the method appears in this file:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/3.8.0/lib/mono/gac/System.Web/4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Web.dll
```

Comment: err ... if you think *you* can *fix* this, than it should be no problem for you to grab the mono-sources (http://www.mono-project.com/community/contributing/source-code-repository/) and change it.

Comment: Did you had any luck solving this problem?